# running a sudo command line from python script does not ask for password, why?

Tags: python, ubuntu, tesseract, sudo

I have a line of code in my python script like this

```
subprocess.run(["tesseract", filepath, "stdout"]
```

what passed to the method by filepath is shown in below image:

[image: some regular text on a picture]

when I run this python script, I get the result like this

```
[1123456789
I"#$%&'II* ,-./

Process finished with exit code 0
```

BUT if I call tesseract from terminal, it was required to be called with "sudo" and I need input my password. just like this image:

[image: result in terminal]

so my question is: I call the same process (tesseract here) in my system, why the root authority was required from terminal while not from python script?

Comment: possibly because your script is being run with sudo privileges

Comment: Also, did the command actually run with sudo?

Comment: how are you calling the script? what are the settings on the script (is it setuid to a different user, possible root?)

Comment: I ran the python script from pycharm, and I started pycharm from the launcher. I'm not sure whether it is provided with sudo, how to check it?